# Drag from one user control and drop into another user control in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create two user controls in Silverlight using the Windows Phone SDK 7.1. I would like to be able to drag from one control and drop into the other control (or at least receive the event that the drop has occurred).

I am able to give the appearance that the drag is moving the item by using a TranslateTransform. However, I would be interested in knowing whether this can be done by actually moving the element instead of transforming it. Can this be done?

Second, and probably more importantly, how do I get the second control to see the drop event? I've done lots of reading, and no luck with this so far.

FWIW, I am currently using a Grid in each control, but I would be open to changing to a Canvas or other control type.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware of windows phone, but we can drag an object from one controller to another controller.(What i did in iOS)

Steps to be followed:

1. Both controllers should be in same window.
2. On ManipulationStarted(touches begin) drag the object or item from one controller, Move on another controller
3. On ManipulationEnded(touches ended) check the dragged object is within the second controller. if Yes, add the object to second controller.

I hope my answer helped you. If it's not useful sorry for that.